# C# .NET 4.8 RestClient call with certificate, basic auth and proxy, fails with an "AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D" error

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a webservice from a C# .NET 4.8 application. The web service is secured via a certificate and basic authentication. When I make the call it is failing with a

> System.Net Error: 0 : [3564] AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with
> error 0X8009030D.

error which leads to a

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

error being thrown.

I have looked at several post but have not been able to make any progress.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = spt;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

RestClient client = new RestClient(uri);

client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(certificate, certificatePassword));

client.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, port);
client.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Message-Key", messageKey);


request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The certificate is a pfx file and when I make the same call using SoapUI it is successful.

I have configured it to produce a System.Net trace log.

The first error is

> System.Net Error: 0 : [3564] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri
> 'https://dev.api.sydney.edu.au/usyd-message-handler-exp-api-v1/v1/messages'.
> Error code: 12180.

I assume this is not an issue as when I didn't have the proxy details the call would timeout.

At the bottom of the log I get:

> [Thumbprint]   0C1EFA37718255EE6DEF3A8A980CD30939762EA6 . System.Net
> Information: 0 : [3564] SecureChannel#14353717 - Found the certificate
> in the LocalMachine store. System.Net Information: 0 : [3564]
> SecureChannel#14353717::.AcquireClientCredentials, new
> SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred,
> SendAuxRecord, UseStrongCrypto), m_ProtocolFlags=(Ssl3Client,
> Tls12Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption) System.Net
> Information: 0 : [3564] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft
> Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     =
> System.Net.SecureCredential) System.Net Error: 0 : [3564]
> AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D. System.Net
> Information: 0 : [3564] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft
> Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     =
> System.Net.SecureCredential) System.Net Error: 0 : [3564]
> AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.
> System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3564] Entering
> Socket#32115247::Dispose() System.Net Error: 0 : [3564] Exception in
> HttpWebRequest#24230272:: - The request was aborted: Could not create
> SSL/TLS secure channel.. System.Net Error: 0 : [3564] Exception in
> HttpWebRequest#24230272::EndGetRequestStream - The request was
> aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.. System.Net
> Information: 0 : [10700] ServicePoint#16495015 - Closed as idle.

For the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol setting I have tried every possible combination, if I do not set it or if I at least include Tls12 then I get this issue otherwise I get an underlying connection was closed error.

Can anyone provide any pointers, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing X509Certificate to X509Certificate2 resolved the issue.